# Why does Ridge Regression work better than LASSO in the presence of multicollinearity?

Tags: lasso, multicollinearity, ridge-regression

I am learning the Ridge Regression. And I found that Ridge Regression is better than LASSO to analyze multicollinear? I wonder the reason?

Comment: Perhaps Section 3.4.3 (p. 69) of Hastie et al. ["Elements of Statistical Learning"](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) (2nd ed., 2009) could be helpful.

Comment: i believe it's impossible that no one has never asked this question before

Comment: Funny that it is the opposite that has been asked before. Being better or not is subjective. Whichever is better depends on the situation/perspective.